# Codebehind not working

Tags: asp.net

This is probably the most simple question ever asked here.  I am learning asp.net on my own using Visual Studio 2010.  But I can't get past the very first example of my tutorial, and have no idea why.  I just can't get the Page_Load event to fire up in the codebehind.  The very simple example is as follows:

default.aspx:

```
<@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"                AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>


<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:Label ID="MyLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
```

default.aspx.vb

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, by Val e As System.Eventargs)
    MyLabel.Text = "Hello, World!"
End Sub

End Class
```

When I add <% MyLabel.Text = "Hello, World!" %> to default.aspx, the label is populated.  I can't get ANYTHING (response.writes, etc) to work within the Page_Load event in the codebehind.

Sorry to bother with something like this, but I can't move forward until I figure this simple problem out.  And I'm stumped.

Comment: Is the file `Build action` on `Page`?

Comment: C# > VB, unless you're just starting out I suppose.

Comment: use CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb"!!!

Comment: @Shawn well on that note MVC > Webforms

Comment: @RahulTripathi I already added that as answer!

Comment: @MikeSmithDev:- Didnt saw that !!! +1

Comment: If you're just learning, I'd really suggest starting out with MVC instead of classic ASP.NET. If you've got the time to learn something new, don't start out with something outdated

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Agreed, wish I had experience with it. :(

Answer (score 7):

It's not working because you didn't tell it to use code behind. The first line in your aspx file should be:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="YourAppName._Default" %>
```

[MSDN ASP.NET Web Page Code Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-Us/library/015103yb.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Also, like others mentioned, you'll either need `AutoEventWireup="true"` or add the `Handles Me.Load` on your `Page_Load`.

Also, if you are just learning.... ASP.NET MVC is a better way to go over Webforms.

Comment: He is not using code behind. While you use codefile, you don't need autoeventwireup="true". Instead in the codefile you say which event it will handle, like [Lee Bailey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18990821/690329) suggested.

Comment: @afzalulh yes I think all there answers here will fix his problem.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  Sorry for another stupid question (I really am a beginner, even though I used to work with classic asp). The project is named WebSite1.  But I'm getting an error by putting 'WebSite1._Default' as my 'Inherits' parameter.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev - yes, I agree.

Comment: @Rob because you setup a website project and not a Web Application. You probably want to go with web application (... or start learning ASP.NET MVC :) [Differences in site vs application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)

Comment: @Rob good place to start: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials or http://www.asp.net/web-forms

Answer (score 3):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, by Val e As System.Eventargs) Handles Me.Load
```

You need to add "Handles Me.Load" so that this method gets run when the Page.Load event is fired.

Answer (score 2):

I think the AutoEventWireup property is a likely culprit, see the explanation on the .net forums:

[Auto event wireup forum post on asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/932513.aspx)

TLDR; set it to "true" and see if that fixes your issue. Another aside, try looking into .NET MVC, because teaching yourself webforms will be great for supporting legacy applications but the trend of new products tends to be MVC framework.